# Update activity content dynamically in android

Tags: android, dynamic, android-activity

I am currently working on a message app and i have an activity that stores recieved messages. So, when this activity(the activity which list the recieved messages) is being displayed if a message comes, how can i dynamically change the content i.e, how can i add the new message to the list. Messages are displayed in textview.

Thank You

Answer (score 0):

assuming that your TextViews are contained by a LinearLayout

```
LinearLayout ll = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.myLL);

TextView tv = new TextView(context);

LayoutParams lp = new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
tv.setLayoutParams(lp);

tv.setText(messageString);

ll.addView(tv);
```

**EDIT**

maybe I didn't understand the situation, if you have just one TextView

```
TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.myTV);

tv.append(messageString);
```